# By default does IIS7 and MVC handle all requests, even images and css files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Does IIS7 and MVC by default handle all requests including javascript/css/images?

Meaning, any requests for a an image will go through the entire MVC pipleline?

I noticed that when a user isn't logged in our authentication system in the Application_AuthenticateRequest redirects the user.  So what is happening is that the page they get redirected to is not able to render any images either.

Is this an IIS7 setting that can be updated to ignore /assets somehow or images type files in general.  Not reason to go through the entire .NET stack for an image in our use case.

I tried adding a location="Assets" in the web.config with anonymous access enabled, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS will serve directly anything that has an extension (.css, .js, etc.). Notable exceptions are of course files with extensions like .aspx, but that's because there's a specific handler assigned for that.

Comment: Yes IIS will serve the file, but will it server it using the asp.net mvc dll?  It seems to be the case for me.

Comment: No, I said it will serve *directly*, as in *not* using ASP.NET. If ASP.NET *is* handling the request, then either a handler has been added for that type (aside from the default static handler) or it's a type that IIS is not aware of at all (sometimes happens with JSON). In which case you just need to add a mime type map to IIS for it.

Comment: No its not json, it is any .css or image file even.  I'll have to ask the admins thanks.

Comment: JSON was just an example of a file type this commonly occurs with.

Answer (score 0):

Since IIS 7.0 all requests go through the ASP.NET pipeline:
Form the [IIS.NET page](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)

> IIS 7.0 and above integrates the ASP.NET runtime with the core web
> server, providing a unified request processing pipeline that is
> exposed to both native and managed components known as modules. The
> many benefits of integration include:
>
> Allowing services provided by both native and managed modules to apply
> to all requests, regardless of handler. For example, managed Forms
> Authentication can be used for all content, including ASP pages, CGIs,
> and static files.
>
> Empowering ASP.NET components to provide
> functionality that was previously unavailable to them due to their
> placement in the server pipeline. For example, a managed module
> providing request rewriting functionality can rewrite the request
> prior to any server processing, including authentication.
>
> A single place to implement, configure, monitor and support server features
> such as single module and handler mapping configuration, single custom
> errors configuration, single url authorization configuration.